4N25 Optocoupler design
Below is a simple 4N25 optocoupler circuit that I designed in LTspice.
10 mA is flowing through the input. It works in saturation. According to the datasheet in Figure 2 (CTR-sat), it says 0.7, so the output of the optocoupler works fine. 7 mA is flowing through the collector of optocoupler, however there is a point of which I am not sure.
As far as I  know the IC of the optocoupler is limited by the CTR so no matter what value I use for R6 to increase the current, the IC stays same. That is okay.
When I increase the current by changing the R6 value for the base of Q2 lets say IB_Q2 = 10 mA the difference between the IC_opto (7mA) and IB_Q2 (10 mA) is still flowing through the base, which is 3 mA approximately when Q2 should be off. This happens when I exceed the current limit defined by CTR so the extra current is flowing when Q2 needs to be off.
Am I thinking in a correct way? What I understand is that there is no need to exceed the Ic of the optocoupler in these kind of circuits. Is that true?

[Simple Optocoupler circuit]

You have a wee bit of an issue with a 100Ω load and this circuit. Generally you'd like the base current of the transistor Q2 to be 1/10 to 1/20 of the collector current, which argues for an R6 of roughly 1kΩ to 2kΩ.
But that requires a large CTR in the optocoupler, which the 4N25 does not really deliver. As Dave says, you also want to allow generous CTR margin for temperature and LED aging. The 4N25, under nominal conditions, has a CTR of better than 20%, however that's with 10V Vce, and close to saturation (which you need to turn off Q2) it will be lower. If you design for a nominal CTR of 10%, there is not enough gain in Q2.
The above is why you should not just play around with parts in LTspice (or on the bench) but use the datasheet guaranteed limits. Generally in a good design we want a circuit that will work every time with any given sample of parts, over an appropriate temperature range, and will work for a long, long time.
There are a few simple things you could do to improve things. For example- change the position of the optocoupler transistor so it turns on Q2 instead of turning it off (allowing for more Vce). You could use a better optocoupler such as one of the PC817 series with a better guaranteed CTR. You could use a Darlington configuration for Q2 (giving up about 0.7V across he load) and increase R6 by something like 20:1. You could replace Q2 with a MOSFET such as AO3400 and increase R6 to 10KΩ or more (but the gate charge would cause slow switching).
A small change from your present arrangement would be something to replace the 4N25 with something like a PC817-B (minimum CTR of 130),change R6 to 2kΩ and stick with the same Q2, which has a decent gain at 100mA.

Indeed. You want to give yourself a good margin relative to the maximum current defined by the CTR, because this will decline as the device ages. You want the 4N25 output transistor to be saturated whenever the LED is on, keeping the base of Q2 well below 0.65 V.
Limiting the current to 1 mA should be sufficient, so R6 should be no less than 10 kΩ.
